# issues faced while extend Role based authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

i faced issues when i tried to extend role based authorization by using Microsoft identity.

when call login action method it will generate token if not added role into claim List.

```
 var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,user.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,user.Id.ToString())
        };

        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);  // If remove this await call then it work fine.

        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }
```

After add new role into Claims while generate Token and i did get any response from server for few min after some time it will shown error like below.

Error is :  Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

In Startup.cs class under ConfigureServices Method.

```
    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            IdentityBuilder builder = services.AddIdentityCore<User>(opt =>
            {
                opt.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                opt.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
                opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                opt.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            });

            builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(Role), builder.Services);
            builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
            builder.AddRoleValidator<RoleValidator<Role>>();
            builder.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<Role>>();
            builder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>();

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(auth =>
            {
                auth.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    // ValidateIssuer = true,
                    // ValidIssuer = Configuration["AuthSettings:Issuer"],
                    // ValidateAudience = true,
                    // ValidAudience = Configuration["AuthSettings:Audience"],
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["AuthSettings:Key"])),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

   services.AddControllers(opt =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
           .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
           .Build();
                opt.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
             .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
              options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

In AuthController

```
 [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserForLoginDto loginDto)
    {

        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginDto.Username);
        var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, loginDto.Password, false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var appUsers = await _userManager.Users.Include(e => e.Photos)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(next => next.NormalizedUserName == loginDto.Username.ToUpper());

            var userToReturn = _mapper.Map<UserForListDto>(appUsers);
            return Ok(new
            {
                token = GeneratejwtToken(appUsers),
                user = userToReturn

            });
        }
        else
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }



    }

    private async Task<string> GeneratejwtToken(User user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,user.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,user.Id.ToString())
        };

        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["AuthSettings:Key"]));
        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = signingCredentials

        };
        var TokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = TokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return TokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that issue,
while calling  GeneratejwtToken method i forgot use await keyword because that method is async method.

```
token = await GeneratejwtToken(appUsers)
```